# XML-XSLT : How to compare two dates which are in String

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I know this question might get repeated and also I have went through similar articles and question but I have not found the exact solution.

Now the question
I am using **XSLT** or **XPATH** to transform the xml. Here in XML two string variables are there.  one is `OldDate` and second is `CurrentDate`.

```
Ex : $oldDate = '29.05.2015 15:25:06'
     $currentDate ='27.07.2015 14:28:02'.
```

Now I want to compare those two dates.

```
If  $oldDate > $currentDate  then 'OK' else 'Not Ok'.
```

As I am new to use **XSLT** and **XPATH** I did not get that how to proceed from the given answers in other articles.

It will be great-full to provide a perfect solution for this.

Thank you.

Comment: You can take this approach: First, format the dates to `yyyyMMddhhmmss` using substring functions. Then convert them to `xs:integer` and compare.

Comment: thank you @LingamurthyCS But your solution would not work.
27-05-2015 is not greater than 29-04-2015. 
but while comparing through integer it gives 29-4-2015 is greater than 27-05-2015

Comment: I suppose the new dates are greater than the old ones.

Comment: @TechnoCracker If you look at the format I suggested(`yyyyMMdd`), the dates would be `20150527` and `20150429`, and would definitely provide the right result when compared.

Comment: Sorry @LingamurthyCS Then I would have not noticed format . I just took given date in integer format.
Yeah sure that solution would also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT (2.0) recognizes dates in `YYYY-MM-DD` format only, and date-times in `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss` format only. In order to compare the strings ***as dates,*** (or, in this case,  date-times), you must first convert them to valid date-times. Since you need to do this more than once, it would be convenient to construct a function for this purpose:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:my="http://www.example.com/my"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs my">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="oldDate" select="'29.05.2015 15:25:06'" />
<xsl:variable name="currentDate" select="'27.07.2015 14:28:02'" />

<xsl:function name="my:string-to-datetime">
    <xsl:param name="string"/> 
    <xsl:variable name="parts" select="tokenize($string,'\.|\s')"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="xs:dateTime(concat($parts[3], '-', $parts[2], '-', $parts[1], 'T', $parts[4]))" />
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="if (my:string-to-datetime($oldDate) gt my:string-to-datetime($currentDate)) then 'OK' else 'Not Ok'" />
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<result>OK</result>
```

Note that this assumes your strings come in a `DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm:ss` format - i.e. that the days are padded to two digits - otherwise there's more work to be done.

Comment: Thank you @michael.hor257k.
Just now I solved practically, but in different way. But your solution looks efficient. I would like to use it.
still I have uploaded my solution too.

Answer (score 0):

Given this input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <oldDate>29.05.2015 15:25:06</oldDate>
    <currentDate>27.07.2015 14:28:02</currentDate>
</root>
```

and this stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="raw_oldDate" select="substring-before(root/oldDate, ' ')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="raw_currentDate" select="substring-before(root/currentDate, ' ')"/>


    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="number(concat(substring($raw_oldDate, 7, 4), 
                substring($raw_oldDate, 4, 2),
                substring($raw_oldDate, 1, 2),
                translate(substring-after(root/oldDate, ' '), ':', '')))
                &lt;
                number(concat(substring($raw_currentDate, 7, 4), 
                substring($raw_currentDate, 4, 2),
                substring($raw_currentDate, 1, 2),
                translate(substring-after(root/currentDate, ' '), ':', '')))">
                <xsl:text>OK</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>not OK</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it produces:

```
OK
```