# How to compare 2 dates

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I know this question might get repeated and i am still learning  ([XML-XSLT : How to compare two dates which are in String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668018/xml-xslt-how-to-compare-two-dates-which-are-in-string))

`EX:<oldDate>2019-09-25T10:49:52.755Z</oldDate>
<currentDate>2019-07-25T10:49:52.755Z</currentDate>`

can some one help me
sample code:
[XML-XSLT : How to compare two dates which are in String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668018/xml-xslt-how-to-compare-two-dates-which-are-in-string)

EXPECTED output:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml>
<output>OK</output>
</xml>`

or

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml>
<output>Not Ok</output>
</xml>`

Please someone help me to compare this kind of date format

Comment: when to show messege `OK` or `Not OK` means both are same then?

Comment: This is clearly a duplicated question from the one that you have linked, unless you show some code and narrow the problem to the string format conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use below code after typecast the string as date `xs:dateTime()`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="if (xs:dateTime(/root/oldDate) > xs:dateTime(/root/currentDate)) then ('OK') else ('Not OK')"/>
```

see this link: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZX6